# Jetifier/AndroidX transforming string in aar

Tags: android, android-jetpack, androidx, android-jetifier

I have an external aar library that is checking if Chrome Custom Tabs are available. They are doing this by creating an intent and checking if the service exists. The intent action is

> android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService

In the aar, this string is being converted to

> androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsService

That change leads to the query to return that the service does not exist.

Not sure if this is a bug with Jetifier or the library or something else. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Jetifier and is tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119183822